# When does a jquery UI tooltip count as initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using a customized jquery UI tooltip, which works nicely. Now I have one specific element where I want to have a delay before the tooltip shows. I am using show: {delay : 1000} as an option, which is ok too. I am defining the tooltip in the document.ready function.

The problem is, I can't find out where to set the delay-option via the setter-method. Whenever I try that, I get an error "can't use that method on tooltip prior to initialization". My current work-around is to re-define the whole tooltip for this one element with the option set, which is ugly. At what point can I actually use a setter-method on an already defined tooltip?

Edit to add sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#selector1').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: 'myTooltip',
        content: function () {
           return genCustomContent();
        }
    });

    $('#selector1 #subElement').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: 'myTooltip',
        show: {delay : 1000},
        content: function () {
           return genCustomContent();
        }
    });
}
```

The above is how my current work-around code looks like. I am not calling the tooltip anywhere else explicitely, as I saw no need to do so - yet. Now the setter for the option I want should look like this:

```
$( "#selector1 #subElement" ).tooltip( "option", "show", {delay : 1000});
```

I have tried calling that directly after the tooltip declaration within the $(document).ready() function, obviously to no avail. I also tried calling it somewhere in the middle of the rest of my code, which is executed well after $(document).ready() has run its course. I get the error message either way.

Comment: I think you can run a timeout on that particular element where you want your tooltip to take more time to appear.

Comment: The delay can be set/changed anytime after you have called `$(selector).tooltip()`. Do you have sample code that can be looked at to see where the issue might lie?

Comment: the jQuery UI tooltip is a bit different if you use it's delegated syntax. When using the delegated syntax, you have to apply all options up front, but the tooltip isn't initialized until you hover over it. If you want to apply specific options to specific ones, you'll have to initialize them separate from other tooltips, usually by using two different classes.

Comment: I edited my message to add examples of the code I am using. So, in answer to Kevin B's contribution - am I getting you right in that I actually can't use the setter as long as I don't call that tooltip "by hand" at some point to ensure it is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't infer what the real problem is. But I think it has something to do with the way you select the tooltip elements for initialization.

HTML

```
<button title="tooltip">normal</button>
<button id="delay" title="this has 1 s delay">delay button</button>
```

SCRIPT

```
  $("[title]").tooltip({
         position: {
             my: "left+15 center",
             at: "right center"
         },
         show: false,
         hide: false
     });
     $("#delay").tooltip("option", "show", {
         delay: 1000
     });
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/forever86/yfy6A/1/).